# SetForgroundWindow() fails after program was Updated

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-7

I wrote an image matching C++ tool which was a notification area tool (no visible window). It got the handle of another window and focused it and then did the image match which it saves. Now this tool was working perfecting but the makers of the program (not written by me) i'm focusing pushed an update which changed their program a fair bit.

As a result I cannot seem to set the focus of the program anymore (bring it to top of all windows). I tried running as administrator with no luck. I can see the icon flash orange in the taskbar meaning its active but the window won't come to the foreground.

Here is my invisible hwnd for my tool:

```
hwnd =  CreateWindowEx (0, className,
TEXT( "" ),
WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
0, 0, 
0, 0, 
NULL, NULL, 
hInstance, NULL);
```

This is the code I had at the top of the function which did the image match:

```
ShowWindow(handle, SW_SHOWDEFAULT); //maximize handle
SetForegroundWindow(handle); //bring to foreground
```

I used SW_SHOWDEFAULT as opposed to SW_SHOW with showWindow as this fixed an issue I had where if the tool was minimised, it would fail to match images as the window was hidden.

It seems like SetForegroundWindow() returns 0 (fail) now when it was working before. I have failed to find online solutions that work.

Only thing that worked (kind of) is this:

```
ShowWindow(handle, SW_MINIMIZE);
ShowWindow(handle, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
```

Which seems to minimize the window and bring it back up which causes it to focus but this is not a solution as the image match process should go on for as long as the user wants.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What is the value returned by `GetLastError()` when `SetForegroundWindow` fails? Have you read the `Remarks` in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539.aspx ?

Comment: I can't seem to get anything from GetLastError() but the return of SetForegroundWindow is definitely 0 (fail). I've looked at the remarks and don't know if i'm failing them. 'Windows flashes the taskbar' is what I am getting implying that I am not meeting the conditions. I just tried double clicking on my icon in the notification area while the tool was trying to set foreground window in a loop and it worked, it managed to set it (because I send last event?). Any ideas?

Comment: The Alt-Tab method on this page has seems to work for me: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/76427/How-to-bring-window-to-top-with-SetForegroundWindo

What are the implications of using this 'hack'. I am tempted to use it if I find no other alternative.

Comment: Window tries hard to forbid "focus stealing", for good reasons.

Comment: One of the rules is that you cannot change the foreground window if you are not yourself foreground. At no point did you set your window foreground, which means that you do not have permission to change foreground. Solution: Call SetForegroundWindow on your hidden window (now you have foreground and have permission to change foreground), then SetForegroundWindow on the other window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the method shown here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/76427/How-to-bring-window-to-top-with-SetForegroundWindo

Answer (score 1):

When SetForeground doesn't work, then you need "focus stealing". Frowned upon, since other programs may rely on focused window.
Basicly, it's only the current foreground window that can set a window belonging to another program to the foreground. This was introduced in Vista I believe.

Use with care, please.

```
bool ForceToForeground(HWND hWnd)
{
    HWND hForeground = GetForegroundWindow(); 

    int curThread    = GetCurrentThreadId();
    int remoteThread = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hForeground,0);

    AttachThreadInput( curThread, remoteThread, TRUE);
    SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
    AttachThreadInput( curThread, remoteThread, FALSE);

    return GetForegroundWindow() == hWnd;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let your application register a (carefully chosen) HotKey via [RegisterHotKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309.aspx) and then simulate the key via [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx)

In the processing of the [WM_HOTKEY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646279.aspx) message, you should be able to "steal the focus".

```
// Register the Ctrl+5 (numpad Hot Key)
BOOL BWin32Success = RegisterHotKey( hWnd, 4242, MOD_CONTROL, VK_NUMPAD5 );

[...]

// Later, Emulate the Hot Key
std::vector<INPUT> vInputs;
INPUT OneInput;

OneInput.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
OneInput.ki.time = 0;
OneInput.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;
OneInput.ki.wScan = 0;
OneInput.ki.dwFlags = 0;

OneInput.ki.wVk = VK_CONTROL;
vInputs.push_back( OneInput );
OneInput.ki.wVk = VK_NUMPAD5;
vInputs.push_back( OneInput );
OneInput.ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
vInputs.push_back( OneInput );
OneInput.ki.wVk = VK_CONTROL;
vInputs.push_back( OneInput );

// Update a global HWND variable with the target hWnd 
UINT Sent = SendInput( static_cast<UINT>( vInputs.size() ), &vInputs[ 0 ] );

[...]

// WM_HOTKEY Handler (message is posted)
case WM_HOTKEY: {
   if ( wParam == 4242 ) {
      // HERE USE THE GLOBAL "TARGET" HWND WITH APIs
   }
   break;
}
```

Comment: So this solution is sending a control+7 message (WM_HOTKEY) in which my program will then be allowed to change the foreground window? I will try this to see if it works, what are the benefits of this over the other method I posted. Many thanks :D

Comment: Control+7 (Num Pad) is a bad choice, indeed. I think that may mess with the standard Ctrl+Home. You have to choose something else, maybe Ctrl+5 (Num Pad). The benefits are, *perhaps*: more reliability over playing with fake mouse clicks. Be sure to deal with `RegisterHotKey` failing`(and retry with another combination)